# Method to remove outline of legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggraph

In R my graph would show legend title as "depth"
When I added guides to change title to capitalize Depth it adds black border around each level in the legend. I'd like to either use another method to rename legend title and keep the gradient look of the levels or remove the black outline.

```
ggraph(df.graph, layout = 'partition') + 
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = depth)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Depth", reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA))
```

I like Depth capitalized but don't like the black border
[image: remove black outline]

I like the gradient, smooth color transition here but not lowercase depth
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand: `Depth`-vs-`depth` is completely under your control using `title=`, and lacking data, I'm assuming that the two legends vary due to `numeric`-vs-`factor` (or `character`). Perhaps it would help if this were reproducible?

Comment: If you just want to set the legend title then you could use `+ labs(fill = "Depth")`. Using `guides(fill = guide_legend(...)` you switched the legend type which for a continuous variable is a colorbar (= `guide_colorbar`).

Comment: @stefan Thanks, that did the trick and I am going to proceed with that and remove guides(fill = guide_legend(...).  Still curious though if the black outline can be removed if using guides(fill = guide_legend(...) for future reference?

Comment: Yep. By default geom_node_tile has a black colored outline which will show up in the legend. To override that in the legend you could do `guides(fill=guide_legend(..., override.aes = list(color = NA)))`